# Extending type in typesctipt

Tags: node.js, typescript

There's this type already available:

```
type GeometryFeature = {
    type: "Feature";
    properties: {
        id: string;
        refId: string | null;
        rootZoneId: string;
        name: string;
        description: string | null;
        startAt: string | null;
        endAt: string | null;
        createdAt: string;
        updatedAt: string;
    };
}
```

I would like to add a few more properties, let's say these two: `fill` of type `string`, `fillOpacity` of type `number` by extending the `GeometryFeature` type. But I would not like to avoid modifying the existing code. The idea behind these two params is to add colour. So I guess, the new type that would include colour related props could be called `GeometryFeatureColored`.

How would you extend the `GeometryFeature` turning it into `GeometryFeatureColored`?

The `GeometryFeatureColored` is expected to look like this:

```
type GeometryFeatureColored = {
    type: "Feature";
    properties: {
        id: string;
        refId: string | null;
        rootZoneId: string;
        name: string;
        description: string | null;
        startAt: string | null;
        endAt: string | null;
        createdAt: string;
        updatedAt: string;
        fill: string;
        fillOpacity: number;
    };
}
```

Preferably, I'd like to know what is the least verbose way of defining this type.

Comment: Please modify the code here so that it's a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Right now there are undeclared types (`Feature`, `Polygon`, `Tags`, `GeomTypes`, etc) that give me unrelated errors if I try to look at it.  Please either remove these types or give definitions for them so that I can get right to work on devising a solution that I can easily test.

Comment: @jcalz Got it. Done.

Comment: Thank you!  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m36BjN) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it pretty much works for me, thank you. But maybe there's a less verbose way of doing it? For example, is the line 17 necessary?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "necessary" here.  It is the case that [you can't simply eliminate it](https://tsplay.dev/wXqvVN), but there are alternative ways of representing the same basic type which have their pros and cons.  You could use [an intersection instead](https://tsplay.dev/wOAl7m), for example. Is your question here meant to be "what is the least verbose way of defining this type?"  If so then please [edit] these additional requirements into the question.  If not, then how would you like me to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I edited the line you proposed into the question. Yes, probably I didn't make it clear, but yes the second solution is what I actually meant and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the least verbose way to write this would be something like

```
interface GeometryFeatureColored extends GeometryFeature {
  properties: GeometryFeature['properties'] & 
    { fill: number, fillOpacity: number }
}
```

Since your `GeometryFeature` interface's `properties` member is of an anonymous type and is not a named interface, you need to use the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `GeometryFeature['properties']` to refer to it.  Then you can [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with the object type containing the properties you wish to add.

Let's test that it works as expected:

```
declare const gfc: GeometryFeatureColored;
gfc.properties;
/* (property) GeometryFeatureColored.properties: {
  id: string;
  refId: string | null;
  rootZoneId: string;
  name: string;
  description: string | null;
  startAt: string | null;
  endAt: string | null;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  } & {
  fill: number;
  fillOpacity: number;
} */
gfc.properties.fill.toFixed(); // okay
gfc.properties.name.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

Looks good.

---

Note that you could also write

```
type GeometryFeatureColored = GeometryFeature & {
  properties: { fill: number, fillOpacity: number }
};
```

which is even shorter, but intersecting at the top level is not completely identical to intersecting in a nested level.  That is, `{a: X & Y}` is similar to but observably different from `{a: X} & {a: Y}`, and I believe you are asking for the former and not the latter.  But I present it as an option in case terseness trumps all other concerns.

---

Personally I prefer to have named interfaces to refer to instead of intersections, since interfaces are more complex when viewed with IntelliSense:

```
type GeometryFeatureProperties = GeometryFeature['properties'];
interface GeometryFeatureColoredProperties extends GeometryFeatureProperties {
  fill: number, fillOpacity: number
}
interface GeometryFeatureColored extends GeometryFeature {
  properties: GeometryFeatureColoredProperties
}
```

As you can see, this is more verbose up-front, but is terser when you start using it (compare to the `GeometryFeatureColored.properties` IntelliSense info above):

```
declare const gfc: GeometryFeatureColored;
gfc.properties;
// (property) GeometryFeatureColored.properties: GeometryFeatureColoredProperties
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-TTEbC9R6fWauYTI0coyRn0caIxKWpqBtNeJpPJIEp9ZtFaVCoZ0glJp+f3EkqbkuA8AwwhuLVVWvFPIHZuHvrH8AAqmBBMdsGIILPNFQ6VMguJSdAACoAd3gVdo4B2z32+qOEFORpaUBI-KfIMIlakjganKkiErWWK4qgBJNiS8ytu2EG0uE4y9jQTIsn+7IqJyEp8o+wJCq+IqXPOUpAf8ioquqpqytqUBkeIFr1FaeZljIujeCxGbJo4bruJ4HGlj6J7+vUgbBqG4allxdSOLGwCDFJSYyTIqYKR00k2tmxZqcMNqFjmOmmJ2-5dE28G-I2RIwWSFJ1hBxnduE-b0WII5Equk7TnI+5OQuLmSiu44bluO57nOva9kelC+rM2xQOeAAWhDQABd6QLqP4EQACtRQ6PF+eGCgaEAQi58L+OsvxbAsGX4cVb6inIOWDnK1x3KmjzfnVL7NUujypTQZl2fioHNrBtngb8SFrCoGzVQ+QJFS+DWXG19xyJ1hXPh8A10blwG1Ut7ArS0vWyv802UIyEDMqyDQcsAXI8rhi3bYajUkYu53iIqCpqkBtFdUd73Gi5L16r+hHvk1+0XX2fmw8Oo7jp5M7hfDpGI65gXrpuvzbruPlXZQoxAA)

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a solution based on Generics, which will allow fast further extension of the `GeometryFeature` type. Generics allow to be able to quickly define `new types based on a template/generic type`

Working playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIQPYFsJigTwDEI4wBXKCABQwAdoxgIBnZAbwFgAoZXv-4ABMAXMmZ5QAcwDc3fv0owAkiLESQk5AB9kIMgBt9snvN5QMGMAC0MICCtHioU46d4g4OR%20ply3glgRnWkZbb2cNbV0DIz9TcTgoMABBMHCpKL1DVzcIEEFU9MidLNiTUyCSSAK0tQjfcvkyWkFSCBqihoBfbm4wfHo0TBw8IiqKCAAeABVkCAAPSHzWdGxcAmJSCZp6JKZWAF4htdHN8kodhn2APmQjzkb%20%20lEAIjOJl5zeWnNdxhZRNNjD0uNwELZxMhJMN1mMtpQlCAEiAkKJViMNuNKHd2F1kHAVjDTliIMZuKBILBECh0bD3pQAMIYfQYKCXPYsOaLPKCQknTHw6h0K6ch68GDAQydHISwwAeVoiGA-VEeiwACNoNwQX0BjSiQLzhAmSzKIIcbTiYLJpbDRMTaz2f9mNdjAB6N3IABWZEhYAwcyRE2QT0CwTAyAA7pL9LpLMhwVhaPo4KAADTIJT4rBxiMBCUgDJwQwhgAWKB%20wo5zDBEIj4NN7TRBrhRodZpxbGQlb%20%201EXdl%20leLwzg4VSpVyAAjAA2ZB4vEE44Y1v25ms9rGBsbwQAOh7IuYu8HOJezBOpakn1rjb3B%20rx5j44QyvwOIArGTQVwPch8BgyATOAQDmAA3PIxAAa2AWgQwDZgIEVSgwH0N8AlAGA5jActu1%20EM9V6LhQ2QZIQEscsoFtfBpj1C0W3pKYqIYp19mQAAydh8TI7DoCoX5Onna5ayRCNgPI6BEWRVESO4iiqJowZ7lwqtnX7LjxLZfjkBeF550XVhSI0%20S9WMMSeKgSSwGApB91%20Q9dzMii%20LoU9r2-bggA)

We need to extract the properties into their own type of interface

```js
interface GeometryFeaturePoperties {
        id: string;
        refId: string | null;
        rootZoneId: string;
        name: string;
        description: string | null;
        startAt: string | null;
        endAt: string | null;
        createdAt: string;
        updatedAt: string;
}
```

Then we can define our template/generic type, where we state that T should be bare minimum GeometryFeaturePoperties and if not provided, it will have default value of GeometryFeaturePoperties.

```js
type GeometryFeature<T extends GeometryFeaturePoperties = GeometryFeaturePoperties> = {
    type: "Feature";
    properties: T;
}
```

Then we need to define our properties extension interface and the extdet type  alias

```js
interface GeometryFeatureColorPoperties extends GeometryFeaturePoperties {
  fill: string;
  fillOpacity: number
}

type GeometryFeatureColored = GeometryFeature<GeometryFeatureColorPoperties>;
```